# JS/JQuery: I Can't get the loop right

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#main-rss-link").click(function() {
        $("#main-rss-link").toggleClass('on'), $("#subscribe-list").slideToggle();
    });
    var a = $("li.comment").attr("id");
    var b = $("li.comment[id='" + a + "']");
    var c = $("li.comment > div.comment-body div > p > a").attr("href");
    if ($.each('#' + a == c)) {
        var d = $("li.comment > div.comment-body div > p > a[href='" + c + "']");
        var e = document.createElement("ul");
        $(e).addClass("children").appendTo(b);
        d.parents("li").appendTo(e);
        $("li ul li div.reply").remove();
    };
});
```

I want it to loop through all of my comments, but it only affects the first one it finds.

Comment: Looking at your code I have a quick suggestion for you, make your variable names more descriptive.  When you come back to the code in a few months you'll have no idea what a,b,c,d,e mean.  If you are worried about saving bytes run your code through a minifier and it'll rename your variables for you.

Comment: Adding to what @bittersweetryan said, using descriptive variable names not only makes your code more maintainable but also more readable - It's a really good habit to get into.

Answer (score 3):

Use [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to loop through your selected comments.

Comment: I added the `$.each()`, but it still isn't working. I updated the problem with `$.each()` inserted to where I believe it was to go.

Answer (score 0):

> I added the `$.each()`, but it still isn't working. I updated the
>   problem with `$.each()` inserted to where I believe it was to go.

Do this

```
$('#' + a).each(function(){  //loop through each a variable 
    if(a == c){              //then, if a is equal to c, do the following
       var d = $("li.comment > div.comment-body div > p > a[href='" + c + "']");
       ....
       ///continue with the rest of the code etc.
    }
};
```